# ASP.NET - Is everything I store in Cache part of the w3wp process?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state, asp.net-cache

It is my understand that the ASP.NET Cache is part of the w3wp process, meaning writing to and reading from it

- does **not** cross process boundaries
- does **not** require marshalling
- does **not** require or perform serialization of objects placed in it

*(All in comparison to using ASP.NET Session State Server which does all these things)*

Is this correct?

Comment: If you are refering to the single HttpApplicationState which is created for each asp.net app then yes, the storage is a primative in memory collection, and doesn't have a provider model like session state that may mean marshalling / serialization.

Comment: @meandmycode Good info, but I do not think Alex refers to the HttpApplicationState class. Do you, Alex?

Comment: @okw/meandmycode: I'm referring to the object that comes with the HttpContext (HttpContext.Current.Cache).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are refering to HttpContext.Current.Cache, then it will be part of the w3wp process. Caching of this form is stored in memory and do not require serialization.

It should not cross process boundaries, it will be a disaster if it does. That goes for marshalling too.